# Trouble nesting if.. then in a loop in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, if-statement, for-loop, nested

I apologize if this is an easy question, I just started macro programming yesterday and have not written in BASIC since qBasic (or any language for a while).  I'm tring to read if a variable is equal to a specific value and, if so, write a different cell into a spreadsheet if it contains data.  I keep getting an error of next without a for.  It runs fine without the first if statement, can someone help me out?  Bonus if you can help on writing the value rather than content, but I can figure that out without bothering you fine folks.  Thanks for the help getting me to this point, this site has been invaluable.  You'll probably recognize some of the coding.

Sub B920LOI()

x = 5
iMaxRow = 3000

For iRow = 3 To iMaxRow

```
If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, "B") = "B920" Or Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, "B") = " B920" Then



    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, "K") > 35 And Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, "K") < 55 Then

    ' Check that cell is not empty.
    ' Copy the cell to the destination
    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, "K")
    .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("920 LOI").Cells(x, "B")

    End With

    x = x + 1


    Else
        'Nothing in this cell.
        'Do nothing.

    End If

Else
        'Nothing in this cell.
        'Do nothing.

End If
```

Next iRow

End Sub

This is the "working version"  Thank you.

Comment: This is what I did, seems to work.  Thank you for your help, reminds me of my Cobol class I took once where a comma caused 10k compilation errors.

Answer (score 7):

Your nests have to match... the "End With" needs to be inside the If block where the With is.

Comment: I apologize, first it wouldn't let me vote up.  I tried moving the End With and it give me an error End With without With (which makes my eyes bleed a bit).  Where do I need to move it?  Thank you for your help.